# Magento Connect: extension submission still "Submitted" in status

Tags: magento-connect

I have submitted extensions to Magento Connect.
Some approved but some extensions are still **Submitted** in status more than 10 days. Extensions created by UMC by @marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon it is just a matter of time and Magento team will approve and reject them soon.

If you want to get more information about your submission, I suggest you contact them directly via email : connect@magento.com

I've contacted them several times and they always replied very fast. Don't forget to specify your extension details as well as your Magento account.

Comment: Any progress? We've had some problems with the connect team recently.

Comment: @RobertEgginton : They ignored my extensions. 
They said sent to developers to review. 
"it must be sent to a Magento developer for further review of the code. We will contact you once the review is compete." More than 1 month for reviewing :( Event reject or what ever, why not update me??

Comment: In the end they came back to let me know that the version numbers in their database did not exactly match up with those in the XML. I provided them with correct version numbers and all went back to normal. The important thing here is to never add a "version" with notes for 1.2 if the uploaded version is 1.2.0.1 - it will cause problems.